# "The subprocess making the call can not access this object because the owner is another thread" Exception ASYNC/AWAIT WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, async-await

I have this code:

```
SecondLog.Opacity = 1;
List<Reporte> Reportes =await Task.Run(() => db_data.TraerReportes(Environment.MachineName, PickFecha.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()));
    if (Reportes.Count  != 0)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre del Proceso");
        dt.Columns.Add("Tiempo Activo");
        dt.Columns.Add("Hora del Ultimo Reporte");
        foreach (Reporte R in Reportes)
        {
            TimeSpan a = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(R.TiempoActivo);
            var Columna = dt.NewRow();
            Columna["t1"] = R.NombreProceso;
            Columna["t2"] = a.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
            Columna["t3"] = R.Fecha;

            dt.Rows.Add(Columna);
            }
            GridReportes.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
        }
```

This returns:

> The subprocess making the call can not access this object because the owner is another thread" exception at line 2 (            List Reportes =await Task.Run(() => db_SpixService.TraerReportes(Environment.MachineName, PickFecha.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()));)

Why is this?

Comment: Just don't try to set the DataContext inside `Task.Run`. Return the datatable and set it *after* the await. That's what `await` is for.

Comment: Better yet, modify `TraerReportes` and make it an *asynchronous* method. Both ADO.NET and Entity Framework have asynchronous functions, eg ExecuteReaderAsync instead of ExecuteAsync. `Task.Run` wastes a thread waiting for the database to respond. `ExecuteReaderAsync` though is a true asynchronous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Exception happens because it is on another Thread than the GUI Thread.

You can wrap the code that access the GUI in this
(you can change `this` with the actual Window object reference):

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    // Your code here
});
```

Not optimal, but you can try this

```
DateTime myDate;
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    // Your UI code here
    SecondLog.Opacity = 1;
    myDate = PickFecha.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
});

List<Reporte> Reportes = await Task.Run(() => db_data.TraerReportes(Environment.MachineName, myDate.ToShortDateString()));
if (Reportes.Count != 0)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Nombre del Proceso");
    dt.Columns.Add("Tiempo Activo");
    dt.Columns.Add("Hora del Ultimo Reporte");
    foreach (Reporte R in Reportes)
    {
        TimeSpan a = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(R.TiempoActivo);
        var Columna = dt.NewRow();
        Columna["t1"] = R.NombreProceso;
        Columna["t2"] = a.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
        Columna["t3"] = R.Fecha;

        dt.Rows.Add(Columna);
    }

    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        GridReportes.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
    });         
}
```

The best is to separate this and only set the GUI elements inside the Invoke

Comment: i can't use await Task.Run(() => db_data.TraerReportes(Environment.MachineName, PickFecha.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString())); inside the dispatcher

Comment: Edited, check if it helps.

Comment: thanks! perfectly worked :). can you explain me what did you do?

Comment: Instead of using `Invoke` to get back to the UI thread, just return the datatable and set the DataContext *after* the `await`. That's what `await` is for - to get back to the original thread/sync context without blocking

Comment: The calls to `Dispatch.Invoke()` here are *outside* the task. They are essentially no-ops unless the *entire* code was called by another thread

Answer (score 2):

```
// this is the part that cannot run on another thread, so prepare it
string param = PickFecha.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();

List<Reporte> Reportes = await Task.Run(() => 
    db_data.TraerReportes(Environment.MachineName, param));
```

You do not need any other changes, you should not need `Control.Invoke()`.
Assuming that TraerReportes does no UI work.